# Can I use re2 library with pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, python-re, re2

I'm using re2 library with Python 3 using this library:
https://github.com/andreasvc/pyre2

I want to use this library inside pandas in this example:

```
pandas_series.str.contains(regex, case=False)
```

It's possible to use pandas and re2 library together in this example?

Comment: Use `pandas_series.apply` and pass a custom method using RE2 regex.

Comment: I know this option, but, It have lower performance?

Comment: There are no other options since `pandas` regex methods use `re`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Pandas regex methods use `re`, you can only use `apply` and pass a custom method using RE2 regex.

You may use

```
import pandas as pd
import re2
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': [ 'abc' , 'def' , '123' ]})
def re2_contains(s, rx):
    return bool(rx.search(s))

rex = re2.compile(r'^[a-z]+$')
>>> df['test'].apply(lambda x: re2_contains(x, rex))
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: test, dtype: bool
```